# Modal window did not update when model changes

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I have a list of groups in my application. when i click on the group, a modal window opens using the modalController with the group related data. form this modal user can make changes to the group. now when i make any change in the group and save it. the changes reflect in the list in the background but not in the modal box.

What i can do here?

Comment: Any code would be helpfull, make a jsfiddle or plnkr with your problem

Answer (score 0):

:(( suplicate::((
Modals in anuglar , regularily has their own instance and controller , they dont get their parrent scope(scope of your view)
So you have to Send this scope(scope of your view) with a resolve property like this :

There should be a resolve property in your modal instance , where you can resolve anything you want ;

```
    yourApp.controller('yourViewController',function($scope,...){
       $scope.openModal = function (size) {
         var modalInstances = $modal.open({
         templateUrl: 'yourModalTemplateURL.html',
         controller: 'YourModalController',
         size: "YourModalSize",
         resolve:{
             info :function(){
                 // you want to see your scope later in your modal
                  // so you have to resolve it and sent it via this property
                 return $scope;
               }
           }
        });
       };
    })
```

And in your ModalController you can inject that **info**

```
   app.controller('YourModalController',function($scope,info){
       console.log(info); // will log the scope of your controller
   });
```

Comment: this is what i am doing right now, but i want the scope variable to refresh based on parent data changes.

So basically if the parent data changes and the modal window is open, it should reflect on the modal window.

Comment: then every thing in your modal , must stick to the scope that comes from your controller with resolve
Are you doing this ?